# Backbone.js Sync is not triggering any events on the model

Tags: backbone.js

I have a very simple setup...

A route is setup that calls a modal dialog using bootstrap. The headerView calls a method when a menu is clicked -

```
menuClick: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.myView) {
        this.myView= new MyView({model: new MyModel()});
    }
    this.myView.render();
},
```

In the MyView I call bind in the initialize

```
initialize: function(){
    this.model.bind('sync', function(model){ alert('test view')});
}
```

And call Backbone.sync in a button click event:

```
var response = Backbone.sync('read', this.model, {
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert('success'); },
    error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ alert(fail); }
});
```

The alert inside the sync gets called...but the alert in the bind command in the initialize never gets called. Tried moving the bind inside the model, moving it out, also tried sync:fail, sync:done. No success.

Comment: Overwrite the `Backbone.sync` is tricky, and looks weird to call it directly.. Why you don't use the high layer commands as `Model.fetch()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not any event is triggered because you didn't say so. You are passing explicit `success` and `error` callbacks which are the ones that have to be in charge of triggering the events.

The native `Backbone.sync` calls from the high layer commands as `save`, `create`, `fetch` receive `success` and `error` callbacks those trigger the events, but you are using your own so this native behavior is obviated.

For [example in the `Model.save`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L377-389), [in the `Model.destroy`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L416-423) and so on.

But, as I said in a previous comment, you really should think if you really need to call `Backbone.sync` directly instead of using more higher layer methods like `Model.fetch()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement the Backbone.sync like this:

```
var sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function (method, model, options) {
    var success = options.success;
    options.success = function (resp, status, xhr) {
        //Your logic goes here
        console.log('succeed');
        if (success) success(resp, status, xhr);
    };
    options.error = function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log('failed');
    }
    sync(method, model, options);
};
```